# Which important Linux tool quotes a popular song if ran after midnight?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

(This is also called an Easter egg, hope it's not offtopic here)

Comment: The easter egg activates half an hour *after midnight*. This is very important, given the lyrics of the song.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be more of a trivia question than a puzzle.

Comment: Please add **computers** and **knowledge** tags.

Comment: for 'computers' I need at least 300 reputation

Comment: I agree that this is trivia question rather than puzzle. (And maybe too easy a trivia question right now, since it's had a bit of publicity lately.)

Comment: And due to the publicity, the latest version will no longer have the Easter egg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is:

> Man
>
> It prints "Gimme Gimme Gimme" at 00:30

Comment: [Related.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405783/129134)